# How to convert a decode URL to bitmap and then shown the image in picturebox in winforms using c#.net

Tags: c#

This is my URL

http://nry.hr2eazy.com//Modules//UserManagement//ImageLoader.ashx?PortalSettingId=1

I am using this code but the image not shown in PictureBox.

```
System.Net.WebRequest request =
   System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://daikin.hr2eazy.com//Modules/UserManagement/ImageLoader.ashx?PortalSettingId=1");
System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
System.IO.Stream responseStream =
   response.GetResponseStream();
Bitmap bitmap2 = new Bitmap(responseStream);
pictureBox11.Image = bitmap2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Load(string)` method like:

```
myPictureBox.Load("https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg?hmac=TmmQSbShHz9CdQm0NkEjx1Dyh_Y984R9LpNrpvH2D_U");
```

Your url is returning as plain text, so there's a little more work to load it, but that should do it:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = client.GetAsync("http://nry.hr2eazy.com//Modules//UserManagement//ImageLoader.ashx?PortalSettingId=1").Result;
var imageStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

Bitmap img = new Bitmap(imageStream);
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
pictureBox1.Image = img;
```

Comment: No ji.... If I am passing ur url its working but I am passing my url it shows a empty picturebox...Not Working

Comment: Because your url is not returning image content in the correct way... it's returning as plain text.
If that url is also your implementation, I recommend you to open another thread asking the correct way to output image content, and I'll be happy to help you with that.

Comment: Thats my question ji....Actually the url output content is decoded text....So that only I used to convert the decode to bitmap and then shown the image to picturebox.....How can I convert that decode stream text to image...Pls give some idea ji

Comment: Check the second part of the answer, I've just updated it!